# I am trying to collect log froms my firewall with logstash using udp but i get this problem

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

^X[INFO ] 2022-08-07 22:24:52.211 [[main]<udp] udp - Starting UDP listener {:address=>"192.168.80.90:5144"}
[ERROR] 2022-08-07 22:24:52.215 [[main]<udp] udp - UDP listener died {:exception=>#<Errno::EADDRINUSE: Address already in use - bind - Ne peut attribuer l'adresse demandéebind(2) for "192.168.80.90" port 5144>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:200:in `bind'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-udp-3.5.0/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:129:in` udp_listener'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-udp-3.5.0/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:81:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:410:in` inputworker'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:401:in `block in start_input'"]}

Answer (score 0):

it means that you have a process already using the port 5144, check with netstat which job is using it and kill it if necessary or change the port.

I had the problem before, I changed the port 5144 with 5145 in the logstash config and in the log forwarding parameter of the firewall and it worked.

Hope it helps you :)